# React. How do I bypass route param to nested element

Tags: react-router

I have a router like this:

```
<Route path="/book/:id?" element={<Container><Book id="dummy-value" /></Container>} />
```

And book component that should work with optional id route param:

```
export default class Book extends React.Component {           
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Book {this.props.id}</h1>                                            
            </div>)
}}
```

up to now Book component renders "Book dummy-value" because id property is set directly to dummy-value. How can Book component take id value from route path (/book/**:id?**) ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have found a workaround: https://www.cluemediator.com/how-to-access-url-parameters-in-the-class-component-using-react-router-v6